# when you add a BigCommerce product to Wishlist, the SKU is not added to {{wishlist.item}} object

Tags: bigcommerce, sku

When you add BigCommerce product to Wishlist, the SKU is not added to {{wishlist.item}} object.
I did a {{log wishlist}}, after the product is added, the SKU is null.

the item object has a lot of key fields that are null like availability, summary, stock_level and also boolean values like pre-order, has_options etc. How can i populate them when adding a product to wishlist?

Is there a way to pass the SKU thru "/wishlist.php?action=addWIshlist&product_id={{product.id}} ??

if possible, how and where can i use JS code to pass this value to the wishlist action everytime i add a product to wishlist?

Answer (score 1):

According to BC's [Wishlist Object documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/theme-objects/c2NoOjg3NzQ5NDA-wishlist), you should have access to the product's SKU. Now, if you have SKUs set at the variant level, and are trying to access that, you will be out of luck. Products only get added to the wishlist at the product level, and do not contain any variant information.

The issue you might be having is you might be trying to access this data on a page where it is not exposed. The only page where this data is exposed is on the wishlist details page for that wishlist. To access it on another page, you would need to make an AJAX request to the wishlist details page.

Comment: The "Add to shopping list" is in the product page, SKU is available in Product Specifications. ISnt there where the product is being added to wishlist? So does this not mean the SKU value is available / exposed ? 
Am I right to assume this?
But your solution about making a request to get the value in the wishlist detail page is a good alternative solution.

Comment: Interestingly, I just tested locally, and I see that SKU is not returned for a product where it should be. This looks like a bug in BigCommerce's code. I would recommend opening a ticket with them if you need this information.

It does look like custom fields are returning properly, so you could add the SKU there as a temporary workaround.